# Portable Device Detection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-ce

I need a functionality in my program (written in VB.NET) that detects whether the USB Portable Device (Windows CE 5.0) is inserted or removed. I have found a VB.NET code from the internet but it only works with USB Storage Devices... I only found codes and sample programs (written in C++) that does this USB Portable Device detection, but I can't understand the logic/program flow so I can't convert it to VB.NET

Here are the VB.NET codes that detects USB Storage Devices (lacks detection for USB Portable Devices):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219

    Public Enum WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS As Integer
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = &H19
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = &H18
        DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = &H8006
        DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = &H8000
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = &H8001
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = &H8002
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = &H8004
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = &H8003
        DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = &H8005
        DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = &H7
        DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = &H17
        DBT_USERDEFINED = &HFFFF
    End Enum

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
            Select Case m.WParam
                Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
                    lblMessage.Text = "USB Inserted"
                Case WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE
                    lblMessage.Text = "USB Removed"
                End Select
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

What must I add to this code so it could detect Windows USB Portable Devices as well?
I need the codes to be in VB.Net...

BTW, Using the program written in C++, it says that my USB Portable Device has the following Properties:

```
VID - 045E
PID - 00CE
```

Thanks for helping out! :)

Comment: Can you more clearly define 'portable devices'?  You say that the code you found only detects storage devices, so what other classes of device are you looking for?  I did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779475/how-to-detect-insertion-and-removal-of-other-usb-peripherals) SO question about detecting USB device insertion.  It might help.

Comment: Oh, sorry. by USB Portable Device i mean Handheld Devices such as Mobile Devices, Barcode Scanners, or RFID Readers... not the typical Flash Drives or External HDDs (Storage Devices) that use USB as their connection to  the PC :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
'Used to detected if any of the messages are any of these constants values.
Private Const WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219
Private Const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL As Integer = &H8000
Private Const DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE As Integer = &H8004
Private Const DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME As Integer = &H2  '
'
'Get the information about the detected volume.
Private Structure DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
    Dim Dbcv_Size As Integer
    Dim Dbcv_Devicetype As Integer
    Dim Dbcv_Reserved As Integer
    Dim Dbcv_Unitmask As Integer
    Dim Dbcv_Flags As Short
End Structure

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef M As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    '
    'These are the required subclassing codes for detecting device based removal and arrival.
    '
    If M.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        Select Case M.WParam
            '
            'Check if a device was added.
            Case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
                Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)
                If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                    Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                    Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))
                    If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To 20
                            If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then
                                Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"
                                MsgBox("Looks like a USB device was plugged in!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
                '
                'Check if the message was for the removal of a device.
            Case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE
                Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)
                If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                    Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                    Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))
                    If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To 20
                            If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then
                                Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"
                                MsgBox("Looks like a volume device was removed!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(M)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: better to give some explanation of your answer in plain words than just throwing away codes !!