# How to detect when a device has been connected/disconnected?

Tags: vb.net, wndproc

I have tried the following:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Const WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219
    Const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL As Integer = &H8000

    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
      If m.LParam.ToInt32=DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
        MessageBox.Show("Device arrival")
      End IF
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

But `m.LParam` constantly returns a value of `7` and hence I am unable to detect when a device is added. I am looking to allow my program to detect when a piece of hardware has been added and if it's a particular device then perform some action (I am not interested in USB mass storage devices so please don't send me any examples regarding this).

Comment: `7` is `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363211.aspx) as: *There is no additional information about which device has been added to or removed from the system. Applications that require more information should register for device notification using the [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) function.*

Comment: Thanks for this information. Do you know where I could attain information on RegisterDeviceNotification function? Or an example of using it?

Comment: Try clicking the link just above.

Comment: I have tried using the code in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779475/how-to-detect-insertion-and-removal-of-other-usb-peripherals and this has not helped matters at all.