# Monitor When a USB Drive is connected with Visual Basic 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, usb, vb.net-2010, usb-drive

I'm looking for a way to monitor when a flashdrive (USB) Is connected to my pc (windows).

My first idea was to use System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives inside a Timer, and check for the new drives that appear, but maybe this could be too CPU demanded (I didn't do it yet)

Do you guys know if there's a better way to do this in Visual Basic 10 ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function RegisterDeviceNotification( _
  ByVal IntPtr As IntPtr, ByVal NotificationFilter As IntPtr, _
  ByVal Flags As Int32) As IntPtr
End Function
```

To register to notification of USB insertion.

Ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431(VS.85).aspx) and an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779475/how-to-detect-insertion-and-removal-of-other-usb-peripherals)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use declare the function in Visual Basic 10 adding "Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices" in the top of my code, but I can't find any example of how to use it inside a windows form based project.