# Disconnecting USB device while program is running

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

Trying to reconnect to USB device after manual disconnection while program is running, basically there is a "click" event occurring starting the program, now what I'm asking is, is there some code to check that it's been reconnected after disconnection.

```
Try
'code executing here, then the device is disconnected while this code is running
 If oflag = False Then 'oflag is false by default
     SerialPort1.PortName = ("Com" & COMnum)     'Assigns the serial port name
     SerialPort1.Open()
 End If
'extra code after this
Catch ex As IOException
     MsgBox("BLAH")
     oflag = True 'this used
     Exit Sub
End Try
```

Comment: You have to override `WndProc` (info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632586(v=vs.85).aspx)) in your base class (a form maybe). When a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message is processed, if `WParam` is `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`, then LParam will give you the device type, which you filter to see if it's what you are expecting. When a device is removed, WParam will be `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`. See [Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect insertion and removal of other USB Peripherals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779475/how-to-detect-insertion-and-removal-of-other-usb-peripherals)